# How to use angular_devise with multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have two devise models: User and Admin. I'm using angular_devise and I can't access Admin routes. By default, login will POST to '/users/sign_in.json' using the resource name user. I would like to know how can I access the route to login Admins.

authController.js:

```js
var controllers;

controllers = angular.module('controllers');
controllers.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Auth',
    function($scope, $location, Auth) {
        $scope.login = function() {
            Auth.login($scope.user).then(function(){
                $location.path('/');
            });
        };

        $scope.register = function() {
            Auth.register($scope.user).then(function(){
                $location.path('/');
            });
        };


    }
]);
```

app.js:

```js
var controllers, library;

controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

library = angular.module('library',
    [
        'ui.router',
        'Devise',
        'templates',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngResource',
        'controllers'
    ]
);

//route

library.config([
    '$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($routeProvider, AuthProvider) {
        return $routeProvider.when('/', {           // HOME ROUTE
            templateUrl: "home/index.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        }).when('/books', {                         // BOOKS ROUTES
            templateUrl: "book/index.html",
            controller:  "BooksController"
        }).when('/books/new', {
            templateUrl: "book/new.html",
            controller:  "BooksController"
        }).when('/books/:bookId', {
            templateUrl: "book/show.html",
            controller:  "BooksController"
        }).when('/books/:bookId/edit', {
            templateUrl: "book/edit.html",
            controller:  "BooksController"
        }).when('/authors', {                       //AUTHORS ROUTES
            templateUrl: "author/index.html",
            controller:  "AuthorsController"
        }).when('/authors/new', {
            templateUrl: "author/new.html",
            controller:  "AuthorsController"
        }).when('/authors/:authorId', {
            templateUrl: "author/show.html",
            controller:  "AuthorsController"
        }).when('/authors/:authorId/edit', {
            templateUrl: "author/edit.html",
            controller:  "AuthorsController"
        }).when('/categories', {                       //CATEGORIES ROUTES
            templateUrl: "category/index.html",
            controller:  "CategoriesController"
        }).when('/login', {                             // AUTHENTICATE USER
            templateUrl: "auth/_login.html",
            controller:  "AuthCtrl"
        }).when('/login_admin', {                             // AUTHENTICATE USER
            templateUrl: "auth/_login.html",
            controller:  "AuthCtrl"

        }).when('/register', {
            templateUrl: "auth/_register.html",
            controller:  "AuthCtrl"
        }).otherwise({                              //OTHERWISE ROUTE
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);
```

NavController.js:

```js
var controllers;

controllers = angular.module('controllers');
controllers.controller("NavController", ['$scope', '$state', 'Auth', '$location',
    function($scope, $state, Auth, $location) {

        $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;
        $scope.logout = Auth.logout;

        Auth.currentUser().then(function (user){
            $scope.user = user;
        });



        // EVENTS
        $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function (e, user){
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:login', function (e, user){
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:logout', function (e, user){
            $scope.user = {};
        });







        // LINKS
        $scope.index = function(){
            $location.path('/');
        }
        $scope.authors = function(){
            $location.path('/authors');
        }
        $scope.books = function(){
            $location.path('/books');
        }
        $scope.categories = function(){
            $location.path('/categories');
        }
    }
]);
```

_nav.html:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="NavController">
    <div class="container-fluid  container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a ng-click="index()" class="navbar-brand" href="">Home</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#/login">Log In</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
                <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="authors()">Authors</a></li>
                <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="books()">Books</a></li>
                <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="categories()">Categories</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#login_admin">Admin Login</a></li>
                <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

routes.rb:

```js
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users

  root "home#index"

  resources :books
  resources :authors
  resources :categories
  get '/search_authors', to: 'authors#searchAuthors'
  get '/search_books', to: 'books#searchBooks'
end
```